# What is the significance of the negative equivalent resistance as an answer in infinite ladder network of resistors?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: **Infinite ladder network **]

when calculating the resistance of this infinite ladder like circuit, the method I used was to assume the equivalent resistance to be $R$.

then we can redraw the circuit as:

[image]

this gives us the equation:

$$ R= 2 + R/(R+1) $$

on solving the quadrating equation, we get two values of R,

R=2.73 and R=-0.73

The equivalent resistance is obviously 2.73, but could the negative solution(-0.73) have a physical significance??

Question: Is it possible to calculate the resistance in a way that the equation to be solved have only *one* positive solution and if not why?

Comment: It means nothing *physically*. An equation with the right solution can also have non-physical solutions. The method of solution to find the resistance you used is essentially equivalent to find the value of an *infinite periodic continued fraction* where the appearance of the multiple solutions of the equation representing the *true* value is standard and you will probably find a more satisfactory answer to the mathematical source of the issue in the math SE than here.

Comment: I would agree with hyportnex that it's non-trivial to interpret this solution. There are, after all, no negative resistances (that would violate energy conservation). There are, however, systems that have negative differential resistance, i.e. the current decreases as the voltage increases. I have a hunch that if we connect such a system with a negative differential resistance of -0.73 Ohm to the output of the three resistor ladder stage, then the differential resistance that we will be measuring between A and B will also be -0.73 Ohm. I might be wrong.

Comment: @FlatterMann That is an interesting suggestion but I think the *definition* of the *infinite* ladder precludes that to happen. I think (note the "think", not "know") an infinite ladder can *only* be defined as the limit of a finite one, and that being the case  the limit is always positive and the spurious root is the result of the continued fraction equated to be equal at any stage to itself. This is related to some complex analysis issues (branch cuts, multivaluedness, etc.) that I barely remember anymore, and that is why I suggested the question be moved to mathSE.

Comment: @hyportnex Your edit appears to have changed the meaning of the question. The OP wants to know the physical significance (if any) of the negative solution.

Comment: @PM2Ring you are right but note too that I also answered the original question in my comment I posted along with the editing that was intended to make sure that the question could not be construed as being a home-work problem. I also removed the home-work label.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes, if you put a resistance of $(1-\sqrt{3})\Omega$ where R is, the resistance of the circuit is $(1-\sqrt{3})\Omega$. Just a routine series/parallel circuit.

Comment: @FlatterMann Practical negative resistances have an external energy source, so energy conservation is not violated. Useful as amplifiers in special circumstances.

Comment: @JohnDoty Agreed. Just saying that in circuit theory we usually have special sources (voltage, current) that are supplying the energy, whereas all other components are either lossless or lossy. In this sense an ordinary resistor is also not "energy conserving", so it's a bit of an artifact of the conventions rather than actual physics.

Answer (score 4):

The usual physical interpretation is that the positive value corresponds to the limit resistance of a finite ladder as its length goes to infinity. This gives a physical justification since in practice, your ladder is always finite, so the infinite limit is a convenient approximation.

For a ladder of length $N$, the resistance $R_N$ can be calculated by induction:
$$
R_N = 2+\frac{R_{N-1}}{R_{N-1}+1}
$$
Note that for a finite ladder, $R_N$ depends on the initial condition $R_0$, or rather physically the final resistance that closes the ladder. Note that in the infinite ladder, you lose information in some sense, as you only have $2$ possible outcomes.

This can be explained by studying the sequence. You can check that the previous function has only two fixed points:
$$
R_\pm = 1\pm\sqrt{3}
$$
$R_+$ is globally attractive, while $R_-$ is unstable. This means that if $R_0\neq R_-$, then:
$$
R_N\xrightarrow{N\to\infty} R_+
$$
and if $R_0 = R_-$, then $R_N=R_-$ for all $N$. You can check this out numerically (better, a cobweb diagram), and if you start with $R_0 = 0$, then you actually obtain the continued fraction expansion of $R_+$.

Since no matter the end resistance of the ladder (with the small exception of $R_-$), the resistance goes to $R_+$, this is the natural resistance to associate to the infinite ladder. The negative solution is just a residual artefact of a rather exceptional dynamic, and in one sense, most of the information of the initial condition gets lost in the limiting process. In fact, it is even more general, the final dipole can be a complex impedance and the result still holds.

Hope it helps.